# Which jQuery or Javascript event fire first with html document?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom-events, page-lifecycle, jquery-events

Is there any jQuery or Javascript event which fire before `$(document).ready();`?

If there are many then can anybody list them with description, please?

I have tried:

```
 $(document).on("pageinit", function () {
        debugger;
        alert("pageinit event fired!")
    });
```

and it is not working, doesn't even fire once :(
I am working in `asp.net MVC`, and I am doing this stuff in a `partial view`

I know I can do the required stuff before rendering the `Partial view`,but just want to know more about it.
`$(document).ready()` event is working fine, but is there any event which fire before this?

Comment: Be aware with javascript inside partial views, [they don't work well together](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7943977)

Comment: try `window.onload = function() { /// };`

Comment: window.onload fires after $(document).ready(); :p

Comment: I think you shown me a right direction @ThiagoFerreira :), I am searching about it